# Why are Google Play games icons not shown in Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games, leaderboard, achievements

I have made [a small game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ardash.raindrops.android) just to test my development skills. I integrated Google Play Game Services, like leaderboards and achievements. **Why are the logos for leaderboards and achievements not shown in the play store?** I'm talking about the logos that indicate, that this app supports the Google Game Services, so games know it.

Where can I enable the setting for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a minimum number of players needed to have signed in and been playing your game before the logos will appear. However, Google has not specifically released the number required, although testing shows it is at least 200.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't know that. As soon as I see it I will report here how many Players it needed.

Comment: Any news on where this information comes from or the players needed?

Comment: I have 5000 of players, and still no achievements and leaderboard icons

Comment: These icons appear to not exist anymore.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I found an app released in 2021 has these icons in the detail description.